# error indicates on this line in code eventCalender.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(events.get(i).getDATE()));

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-applicationinfo

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference at java.util.Calendar.setTime**

```
        TextView Day_Number = view.findViewById(R.id.calender_day);
        TextView EventNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.event_id);
        Day_Number.setText(String.valueOf(DayNo));
        Calendar eventCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
        ArrayList<String>arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i < events.size();i++)
        {
           eventCalender.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(events.get(i).getDATE()));
            if(DayNo == eventCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && displayMonth == eventCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1
                    && displayYear == eventCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR))
            {
                arrayList.add(events.get(i).getEVENT());
                EventNumber.setText(arrayList.size()+"Events");
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```